# Limit of two variables with trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I need to calculate this limit which involves trigonometric functions

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(1, 8)} \frac{\tan(y-8) \sin^2(y-8x)}{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 8)^2}$$

I used mathlab to evaluate and got $0$, but I haven't managed to get this algebraically

How can I approach this question?

Comment: Hint: for small arguments of $\tan$ and $\sin$, you can replace the function by its argument. And you can rework the expression in polar coordinates around the pole $(1,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(1, 8)} \frac{\tan(y-8) \sin^2(y-8x)}{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 8)^2}$$

Put $u=x-1$ and $v=y-8$, the limit is transformed to :

$$\lim\limits_{(u,v)\to(0, 0)} \frac{\tan(v) \sin^2(v-8u)}{u^2 + v^2}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{(u,v)\to(0, 0)} \frac{\sin(v) \sin^2(v-8u)}{u^2 + v^2}$$

Now $$\left|\frac{\sin(v) \sin^2(v-8u)}{u^2 + v^2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{v(v-8u)^2}{u^2 + v^2}\right|\leq \left|\frac{v^3}{u^2 + v^2}\right|+\left|\frac{16uv^2}{u^2 + v^2}\right|+\left|\frac{64u^2v}{u^2 + v^2}\right|$$

It is not difficult to show that the limit of these three terms as $(u,v)\to(0,0)$ is $0$.

Comment: Why is $\lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} \frac{\tan v \sin^2 (v-8u)}{u^2+v^2}=\lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin v \sin^2 (v-8u)}{u^2+v^2}$? Is that because $\lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{\cos v}=1$ and so you're ignoring it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is why I am ignoring it.